# How to only allows IP within given range in asterisk?

Tags: asterisk

In asterisk How can i allows IP which are in given range.In dialpan I define global variable like IP=192.168.50.0/30.how can I allow IPs with in given range

Answer (score 0):

Do it with 
`deny=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
permit=192.168.50.0/255.255.255.0`

Answer (score 0):

In Asterisk dialplan.`      [globals]
      IP=192.168.50.0
      MASK=24

```
  [test]
  exten => _X.,1,Set(OutPUT=$[${SHELL(php -f ${ASTVARLIBDIR}/agi-bin/ipnotify.php ${recvip} ${GLOBAL(IP)} ${GLOBAL(MASK)} )}])
  exten => _X.,n,Set(recvip=${CHANNEL(recvip)})
  exten => _X.,n,Gotoif($["${OutPUT}"="1"]?InOffice:outOfOffice)
```

`In ipnotify.php`

```
  <?php
  $ip=$argv[1];
  $net_addr=$argv[2];
  $net_mask=$argv[3];

  function ip_in_network($ip, $net_addr, $net_mask){
  if($net_mask <= 0){ return false; }
  $ip_binary_string = sprintf("%032b",ip2long($ip));
  $net_binary_string = sprintf("%032b",ip2long($net_addr));
  return (substr_compare($ip_binary_string,$net_binary_string,0,$net_mask) === 0);
  }
  echo ip_in_network("$ip","$net_addr",$net_mask);
  ?>`
```

Comment: Never, never use agi for access check. That will cause server go down on any single low-volume attack.

Answer (score 0):

Correct setup will be use iptables rules:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m udp -p udp --destination-port 5060 -s 192.168.50.0/30 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m udp -p udp --destination-port 5060 -j DROP
```

All other solutions(including permit in asterisk) will eat your resouces while you under automated attack.